# javax.mail.Session no existe

Tags: java, eclipse

como importo javax.mail.Session

he probado a descragar los .jar; mail.jar javax.mail.jar
javax.mail-api-1.4.4.jar

los he importado a librerias Los he añadido al path   --   `set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;C:XXXX\XXXXX\javamail\mail.jar`

pero nada,siguen
sin "existir", alguna idea?

```
    package handlers;
    
    import java.util.Properties;
    
    import javax.mail.Session;
    
    public class Senders {
        private Senders() {
            
    }
    private static final String SENDERS_GMAIL = "xxx@xxx.com";
    private static final String SENDERS_PASSWORD = "hackerman";
    private static final String RECIEVERS_EMAIL ="xxx@xxx.com";
    private static Properties mailServerProperties;
        private static Session mailSession;
        
    }
```

(solo es una parte)

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. ¿Cuándo te dice que no existe? No es claro cuándo o dónde modificas el classpath (¿cuando corres tu aplicación?). Habría que revisar si están correctamente importados en las librerías de tu proyecto.

Comment: Yo he descardo el jar, lo he importado en la sección de libreries en el Java Build Patch y no da problemas.

Comment: Puede servirte [package javax.mail does not exist](https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/1662610#32514721) igual en el hilo hay gran cantidad de alternativas y todas son validas.